# PHP uploaded mp4 files wont play in the video tag

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to allow users to upload .mp4 files to a server so users can view those files on the site.
I keep getting errors about how the source cannot be decoded

javascript code :

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file',document.getElementById('fileupload').files[0]);
xhr.open('post','./beeldbank/beheer/upload.php',true);
xhr.send(fd);
```

PHP code :

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/assets /video/" . $counter[10] . ".mp4");
```

This completely fails on firefox. Audio only on chrome. IE = unsupported video type  or invalid file path

If i download the files from the server through filezilla vlc plays them perfectly.

Comment: "If i download the files from the server through filezilla vlc plays them perfectly." - Does that mean that the uploader script is working fine? Are you having problems with having users view the files?

Comment: Yes uploading the files themselves has no issues, just the playback on the site does not work at all

Comment: @battlenub thats because the video tag is in orrect for playing audio files you need to use the audio tag for it

Comment: My problem is about .mp4 files

Comment: You have not put up any code about how do you allow access to the audio files here? Direct links to them?

Comment: Make sure Firefox actually supports playing your codec. See: [Media formats supported by the HTML audio and video elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats). IIRC Firefox should give an error about this in the error console.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a regular text or html file in the folder you are uploading the files to. Are they accessible from the browser?